# How to search encrypted value's actual data in table

Tags: java, database

I have an encrypted value (xyz), and I want to find the actual data from the table.
eg:
1000 (Actual value) -> XYZ (Encrypted value)

1000 is the id of the table, I want to fetch the id 1000 row. How can I do that in a simple way?